# XML - Trying to grasp the concept of namespace URI

Tags: xml, url, uri, transformer-model, urn

If my XSL have the following heading, I get no error :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
```

But if I change the xsl namespace URI... :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp"
```

...I get an error :

```
javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException
```

I think I do not understand the concept of a namespace URI, because I though that it could be any URL (not to mention URNs) as long as it was unique in the XML/XSL document. Obviously not. I tried to change the URI to test this theory.

---

At https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp, we can read the following statements :

> The namespace URI is not used by the parser to look up information.
>
> The purpose of using an URI is to give the namespace a unique name.
>
> However, companies often use the namespace as a pointer to a web page containing namespace information.

The first statement means that we don't care about what is the web page pointed by the URI, so why can't I set it to point any page I want, or even a page that does not exist ? Why does it have to specially be http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform ?

Furthermore, later on the above link we can read :

> A Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) is a string of characters which **identifies an Internet Resource**.

So, because  of this and because "The purpose of using an URI is to give the namespace a unique name", does it mean that **a namespace URI has to be an URL** (again, no to mention URNs which I absolutely can't fathom), which means that I can't set a namespace like this :

```
xlmns:foo="A_random_but_unique_string"
```

I would finish with this quote from the same link :

> The namespace "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" identifies XSLT elements inside an HTML document

So now it means that the parser must certainly use the namespace URL to look up for information (the elements of the namespace), no ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with resolving URL's (and downloading schemas). Even though the XML looks the same in both examples: "xsl:stylesheet", your input is read as a `stylesheet` element (identified by namespace `https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp`).

The Java program expects a `stylesheet` element (identified by namespace `http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform`) however and since it cannot find it it throws an exception.

Comment: Thank you for you response.

Why does it expect a stylesheet element from the namespace identified by the URI http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform if it doesn't even need to extract any information from this URL ? I mean, the Java program doesn't have the knowlege of what a stylesheet element is from this URL ! A stylesheet is a stylesheet no matter the URI.

Comment: Because the Stylesheet is not a random/custom format, but is a w3 standard. Java already has the schema definition (XSD) of this standard and thus when preparing a transformation it'll try to see if this matches its expectation.
It does not know how to interpret a stylesheet from w3schools, but it knows it can parse/interpret a XML file that validates to the w3.org stylesheet schema (which is uniquely identified by ... that exact URI).

Comment: Shorter answer: The stylesheet with the w3schools URI is not valid according to the stylesheet's XSD.